# Is the deductive closure of a theory minus a finite set of sentences, the same theory again?

Tags: model-theory

Let $L$ be a first-order language, and let $T$ be a theory, that is, a consistent and deductively closed set of sentences of $L$. Let $F$ be a finite set of sentences in $T$, and consider the deductive closure of $T - F$. Is that the same theory $T$ again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Every sentence has infinitely many deductively-equivalent variations (for example, just take iterated conjunctions with $\top$). So as long as you only remove finitely many sentences from $T$, there will be sentences deductively-equivalent to those you've removed which are left over.

Of course, this crucially requires that $T$ itself be deductively closed to start with, so that $T$ contains all the sentences deductively-equivalent to any sentence in $T$. (Consistency, meanwhile, is not needed.)